# AWS S3 returns "POST 400 bad request" for fileupload using plupload

Tags: java, file-upload, amazon-s3, plupload, http-status-code-400

I am trying to upload directly to AWS S3 with the help of plupload. I am using

```
https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/examples/jquery/s3.php and 
https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/wiki/Upload-to-Amazon-S3
```

as references. 
But i am doing it with JSP and Servlet.

when i try to upload a file , it displays "server responded with status of 400- bad request".
here is my files :
upload.jsp ::

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plupload/jquery.plupload.queue/css/jquery.plupload.queue.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div style="width: 750px; margin: 0px auto">
                <div id="uploader">

                    <p> Flash, Silverlight, Gears, BrowserPlus HTML5 .</p>
                </div>
                <input type="button" value="Clear" id="clear"/>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plupload/plupload.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plupload/jquery.plupload.queue/jquery.plupload.queue.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="plupload/i18n/cn.js"></script> -->
<script >
/* Convert divs to queue widgets when the DOM is ready */


$(function(){
    //ajax call to servlet for details
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        //dataType : "text" ,
        url : "UploadCon2",
        success : function(data)
        {   
            plupload(data);          
        }
    });

    function plupload(data){

        var flag_arr = data.split(" ");
        var bucket = flag_arr[0] ;              
        var policy = flag_arr[1] ;
        var signature = flag_arr[2] ;
        var access_key_id = flag_arr[3];
        alert(signature);
        $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({

            // General settings
            runtimes : 'html5,gears,browserplus,silverlight,flash,html4',

            unique_names : true,

            // Flash settings
            flash_swf_url : 'plupload/plupload.flash.swf',
            // Silverlight settings
            silverlight_xap_url : 'plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap',



            url : 'http://'+bucket+'.s3.amazonaws.com/',
            //url : 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/'+bucket+'/',

            multipart: true,
            multipart_params: {
                'key': '${filename}', // use filename as a key
                'Filename': '${filename}', // adding this to keep consistency across the runtimes
                'acl': 'public-read',
                'success_action_redirect' : 'http://localhost/' ,
                'Content-Type': '',
                'x-amz-credential' : 'MYACCESSKEY/20160211/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request',
                'x-amz-algorithm':'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
                'x-amz-date' : '20160211T000000Z',      
                'policy': policy,
                'x-amz-signature': signature,
            },


        });

    }
    plupload();
    $('#clear').click(function(){
        plupload();
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

servlet ::
UploadCon2.java

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.ThrowsPattern;

import com.amazonaws.auth.policy.Policy;
import com.amazonaws.util.Base64;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class UploadCon2
 */
@WebServlet("/UploadCon2")
@MultipartConfig
public class UploadCon2 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
//  private static final String JSON = null;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public UploadCon2() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

        /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String bucketName = "thehexa4";
        String access_key_id = "myaccesskey";
        String secret_access_key = "secretaccesskey";


        String policy_doc =
                  "{\"expiration\": \"2016-12-30T12:00:00.000Z\"," +
                    "\"conditions\": [" +
                      "{\"bucket\": \"thehexa4\"}," +
                      "[\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"\"]," +
                      "{\"acl\": \"public-read\"}," +
                      "{\"success_action_redirect\": \"http://localhost/\"}," +
                      "[\"starts-with\", \"$Content-Type\", \"\"]," +

                      "[\"content-length-range\", 0, 10485760]" +
                      "{\"x-amz-credential\": \"myaccesskey/20160211/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\"}," +
                      "{\"x-amz-algorithm\": \"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\"}," +
                      "{\"x-amz-date\": \"20160211T000000Z\" }" +
                    "]" +
                  "}";
        System.out.print(policy_doc);
        // Calculate policy and signature values from the given policy document and AWS credentials.
        String policy = new String(Base64.encode(policy_doc.getBytes("UTF-8")), "ASCII");

        //HMAC SHA 256 calculation
        String signingkey = "";
        String signature = "";
        try {
            signingkey = getSignatureKey(secret_access_key,"20160211" , "us-east-1", "s3").toString();
            //signature = Base64.encodeAsString((HmacSHA256(signingkey, policy.getBytes())));
            signature = Hex.encodeHexString(HmacSHA256(signingkey, policy.getBytes()));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write(bucketName+" ");
        out.write(policy+" ");
        out.write(signature+" ");   
        out.write(access_key_id+" ");
    }

        private byte[] getSignatureKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName) throws Exception{
             byte[] kSecret = ("AWS4" + key).getBytes("UTF8");
             byte[] kDate    = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
             byte[] kRegion  = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
             byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
             byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
             return kSigning;
        }


        private byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String algorithm="HmacSHA256";               
             Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
             mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm));
             return mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
        }   

}
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance :)
[pls tell me if u require more info about my code]